# i'm getting error in php code. trying to access input value in php on wamp server. it gives error as undefined variable but my code is correct

Tags: php, html, wamp

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="add.php" method="post"  >
<input type="text" name="user" />
<input  type="number" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

======================================================================================================
//php code

<?php
$n=$_post['user'];
$a=$_post['age'];
echo "Hello $n your age is $a";
?>
```

i am getting the error message that the variable is not found but my code is correct how to resolve this issue

Comment: `$_post` should be `$_POST`. Variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Parashar please do some research in your own way before asking. It will helps you alot.

Answer (score 1):

The official superglobal's variable name is `$_POST`. You cannot replace it with `$_post` as it is case-sensitive.

Shoutout to @Barmar in the comments.